# How to get this DataList with the paging property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a web-based application in which I have a DataList and I need to have a paging feature. I followed what is explained in this post in the CodeProject, but it did not work with me and I got this error which I could not be able to understand it.

**Error:**

> The name 'CurrentPage' does not exist in the current context.

**So how to fix this error  and get the Paging feature in this DataList?**

ASP.NET code:

```
<tr>
            <td width="100%">
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink
                                            ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "StartQuiz.aspx?testid=" + Eval("QuizID") %>'
                                            Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink><br />
                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label
                                        ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" CssClass="generaltext" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
                                    <br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [Description], [QuizID],[IsSent] FROM [Quiz] where [IsSent]=1 order by [QuizID] DESC">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>                                         

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentPage" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="cmdPrev" runat="server" Text=" << " OnClick="cmdPrev_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="cmdNext" runat="server" Text=" >> " OnClick="cmdNext_Click" />

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void items()
    {
        PagedDataSource objDs = new PagedDataSource();
        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        objDs.DataSource = dv;
        objDs.AllowPaging = true;
        objDs.PageSize = 5;
        objDs.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page:" + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " Of " + objDs.PageCount.ToString();
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !objDs.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !objDs.IsLastPage;
        DataList1.DataSource = objDs;
        DataList1.DataBind();

    }


    protected void cmdPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CurrentPage -= 1;
            items();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    protected void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            CurrentPage += 1;
            items();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're always using the variable `CurrentPage` but you haven't shown where it's declared and initialized. Maybe the compiler complains of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Declare "CurrentPage variable at the Top of everything" i believe in your case it should be int CurrentPage = 1;